# Looking for help, Aluffi Exercise 5.13, Chapter 6: characterization of PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I quote:

"Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over an integral domain $R$.

Prove that if $R$ is a PID, then $M$ is torsion-free if and only if it is free.  Prove that this property characterizes PIDs. (Cf. Exercise 4.3.)"

I am having trouble on the second part.  Btw, Exercise 4.3 says that an integral domain $R$ is a PID if and only if its ideals are free as $R$-modules, which is easy to see.

I am not sure if I am interpreting Aluffi correctly, but I think I am.  Here is how I have written the problem:

*Let $R$ be an integral domain.  IF*

*($\forall M$ finitely generated $R$-modules): ($M$ is torsion-free $\Longleftrightarrow$ every ideal of $R$ is free as an $R$-module),*

*THEN*

*$R$ is a PID.*

---

I figured I was supposed to prove that every ideal $I$ of $R$ is finitely generated, i.e. $R$ is Noetherian, so that $I$ being torsion-free (it is a submodule of the free module $R^1$) implies $I$ is a free $R$-module.  But I have made pretty much zero progress...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I only know that now, after this discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are commutative domains (for example, any non-Noetherian valuation domain) which are not PIDs but for which every finitely generated torsion-free module is free.

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then either I misinterpreted Aluffi or his statement is wrong.

Comment: @DanDouglas I suspect that Aluffi meant to specify "Noetherian".

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear that free always implies torsion-free. So it suffices you assume $R$ is a domain where every torsion-free module is free. As noted in the comments, one should assume $R$ is noetherian. Now every ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $R$ is certainly torsion-free, so it must be free. Assume this is generated by more than *one* element. Let $a_1,a_2$ be distinct generators. Then $a_2a_1-a_1a_2=0$ is a dependence relation $b_1a_1+b_2a_2=0$, which implies $b_1=b_2=0$, contradicting $a_1,a_2$ are part of a basis. Note I didn't assume the ideal was finitely generated.

**ADD** One can show that in a domain where every finitely generated ideal is principal, torsion-free is equivalent to flatness. So you have a nice result that for PIDs, free equals projective equals flat.

Comment: But the condition is that every **finitely generated** torsion-free module is free. If **every** torsion free module for a domain is free, then the domain must be a field.

Comment: @Pedro:  But the way I've stated the problem, you cannot assume $\mathfrak{a}$ is free unless you first show it is finitely generated.